# How to set weak reference to a class member e.g. callback method?

Tags: ios, swift

While playing with Swift's ARC mechanism, I noticed that you cannot create a weak reference to  a non-class member or you would get the compiling error "weak cannot be applied to non-class type X", so if I would like to pass a callback to another class for example:

```
class A{
    var b:B?
    init(){
        b = B(callback)
    }

    func callback(name:String){
        print("name: \(name)")
    }

    func trigger(){
        if b != nil{
            b!.somethingHappenedHenceCallback()
        }
    }
}
class B{
    var method:((name:String)->Void)
    init(method:(name:String)->Void){
        self.method = method
    }

    func somethingHappenedHenceCallback(){
        if method != nil{
            method(name: "From class B")
        }
    }
}
var a:A = A()
a.trigger()
```

In the previous example I'm passing the "callback" method to the class B, so, if I need to be notified when something happens, the class B can call it and it will be executed in class A, and it works perfectly, the only problem is that it creates a strong reference to A from B, and it will not allow A to be deinited when A is set to nil because B is keeping a strong reference, so I know that if I do the following it will work:

```
class A{
    var b:B?
    init(){
        b = B(a:self)
    }

    func callback(name:String){
        print("name: \(name)")
    }

    func trigger(){
        if b != nil{
            b!.somethingHappenedHenceCallback()
        }
    }
}
class B{
    var a:A?
    init(a:A){
        self.a = a
    }

    func somethingHappenedHenceCallback(){
        if a != nil{
            a!.callback("From class BB")
        }
    }
}

var a:A = A()
a.trigger()
```

However, is there a way to make a weak reference to the member only(in this case the method) instead of having to pass a reference to the whole class?

Regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than just passing a reference to `callback` to the initializer for `B`, create a closure that uses a `weak` or `unowned` reference to `self`:

```
class A{
var b:B?
init(){
    b = B { [unowned self] in self.callback($0) }
}
...
```

---

Also, you have a couple other issues in your code:

```
if b != nil{
    b!.somethingHappenedHenceCallback()
}
```

is not idiomatic swift; the preferred way to express this is

```
if let x = b {
    x.somethingHappenedHenceCallback()
}
```

And `if method != nil` is unnecessary, and could possibly give a compiler error; the type given for `method` is not an optional and therefore it can never be `nil`

Comment: How do you create a closure that uses a weak or unowned reference to self? I tried but as I said you can't have weak references of non-class types, so even tho we have a weak reference to self, the closure it self will not be weak and when passed to B it will hold a strong reference to it, or maybe I didn't understand what you meant by that, could you be more precise about it? Maybe an example of "a closure that uses a weak or unowned reference to self"?, BTW thanks for the IF advices :)

Comment: At the start of a closure definition, in `[]` you can put a capture list that lists which references inside the closure should be weak or unowned. In my answer you can see that in `{ [unowned self] in self.callback($0) }`. It doesn't matter if B.method is a strong reference to the closure, because the closure itself contains only an unowned reference to `A`. You can find more details at  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_62